# Ajax fail in all versions of IE

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have this Ajax post request.  Works great in Crome.  Just opened it in IE and it fails completely.  It is a div with images loaded into a carousel.  The carousel used is http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/ (Which I would highly recommend for its easy implementation if anyone is after an image carousel)

When you click a folder

```
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getImages(1)">Folder 1</a>
```

basically queries a php file and refreshes the div with a new set of images

```
  $.ajaxSetup ({  
    cache: false,
    async: false  
});  
 function getImages(id)
 {
 $.ajax({


 type: "POST",
 url: 'getImage.php',
 dataType: "json",
 data: "id=" + id, 
 success: function(data) {

      $('#scrolimg').html(data);
      $("#car1").carouFredSel({
auto : false,
items   : 4,
scroll  : 4,
circular : false,
infinite : false,
prev : "#foo1_prev",
next : "#foo1_next",
swipe       : {
    onTouch     : true,
    onMouse     : false
}
 });

 }

 });
```

When I have been reading similar problems on Stack most people say turn cache to false and async but that has not helped.  Another solution was to make POST requests instead of GET but thats does not work for me either.

**The code above works perfectly.**   The problem is in the getImage.php file.  I have a loop thats running to find the image width and height with php function call getimagesize()

That function is not running in IE but working perfectly in all other browsers.  Is my Ajax blocking this function from running?

```
   <?php do {
  $image = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/uploads/".$row_rs_image['thumbfile'];
   list($width, $height)= getimagesize($image); 
 ?>
     <img  src="/images/uploads/<?php echo $row_rs_image['thumbfile']; ?>"  width="<?php echo $width;?>" height="<?php echo $height;?>" />
    <?php } while ($row_rs_image = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_image)); ?>
```

When I output the source I see the following

```
       <img name="creed" src="/images/uploads/320623-1358872780_thumb.png"  width="" height="" />
```

Comment: You should specify the version of internet explorer in your original post.

Comment: Don't use `async: false`.

Comment: Have you looked at the Dev Tools to see what the actual HTTP request/response look like?

Comment: @Dean all versions of IE fail.

Comment: @SDC how do you look in dev tools in the correct way to test this

Comment: Normally the case for this is a trailing comma in JSON or an object. Check that the last items in all your objects + JSON don't contain any trailing commas.

Comment: @SLaks I have removed that line as well as data type as that stopped it in all browsers but it still does not work

Comment: @Dean Thanks Dean.  Tried that but to no avail.  Im completely confused as to whats going on.  Why would it work perfectly in other broswers?

Comment: @DanielRobinson - to examine HTTP request/response in IE: First, get the page to the point you want to test, then: F12 to open dev tools; Click "Network" tab; Click "start capturing". Then do the action on the page that should trigger the ajax event. If the ajax was called, the dev tools window should now show the request. If so, click it to see the the details about what was sent and recieved.

Comment: @Dean thanks thats great.  I can now see the ajax call is working fine.  My function in getImage.php called getimagesize() is not working but only in IE

Comment: FYI, `$.ajaxSetup` will need to be `$(document).ajaxSetup` in 1.9+ and 2.0+ versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue.  on get image sizes use this line instead

list($width, $height, $type, $sizes)= getimagesize($image);

then in the getImage.php

```
  <?php do {
  $image = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$row_rs_image['userimagespath'].$row_rs_image['thumbfile'];
   list($width, $height, $type, $sizes)= getimagesize($image);  
 ?>
  <img name="<?php echo $row_rs_image['imgname']; ?>" src="/images/uploads/<?php echo $row_rs_image['thumbfile']; ?>"  <?php echo $sizes;?> />
```

Thanks to everyone for the help

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the comma, try it, hope it will work :)

$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false,
    async: false
});
 function getImages(id)
 {
 $.ajax({

type: "POST",
 url: 'getImage.php',
 dataType: "json",
 data: "id=" + id
 success: function(data) {

```
  $('#scrolimg').html(data);
  $("#car1").carouFredSel({
```

auto : false,
items   : 4,
scroll  : 4,
circular : false,
infinite : false,
prev : "#foo1_prev",
next : "#foo1_next"
swipe       : {
    onTouch     : true,
    onMouse     : false
}
 });

}

});

Comment: in which version if IE are u trying?

Comment: I have now tried all of them.  Its completely fine in Chrome.  When you click the link the images currently loaded disappear and no new ones are loaded in all IE versions.